# RDP windows key jamming

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

There is a known bug in RDP; if you lock the screen while connected to a computer the computer you are connected to will have its windows key jammed.

There are a few work arounds that involve hammering the windows key and re-locking the screen but this isn't a bug I want to put up with anymore.

Microsoft has said they wont fix this bug because it's XP specific and they are only working on security bugs now because XP is at end of life.

Is there any way I can fix this or am I just going to have to find an alternative remote desktop software.

Comment: Just since no one has answered I'll try: does this happen to both PS2 and USB keyboards?

Comment: It does happen with both types.

Comment: and when you say lock the screen, do you mean lock the computer?

Comment: Yes, Using the key command WIN + L

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in the DLL library associated with mstsc.  By unregistering and re-registering it (or reinstalling mstsc 6.1) - the problem normally goes away.